# Using one render pass on top of another

Tags: c++, rendering, render, vulkan

I'm trying to implement imGUI in my app which already have some render pass for rendering meshes. Its command buffer updates only when new meshes added to scene, while imGUI command buffer should be updated every frame. Secondary command buffer doesn't fits me because I always have to reference it from primary cb, which doesn't update so often.

I also want to mention that my code is based on [this](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/) tutorial.

I came to conclusion that I should have two render passes with two primary command buffers. The only problem now is that I can't combine these two render passes.

There is the code for main rp:

```
    vk::AttachmentDescription colorAttachment;
    colorAttachment.format = swapChainImageFormat;
    colorAttachment.samples = vk::SampleCountFlagBits::e1;
    colorAttachment.loadOp = vk::AttachmentLoadOp::eClear;
    colorAttachment.storeOp = vk::AttachmentStoreOp::eStore;
    colorAttachment.stencilLoadOp = vk::AttachmentLoadOp::eDontCare;
    colorAttachment.stencilStoreOp = vk::AttachmentStoreOp::eNoneQCOM;
    colorAttachment.initialLayout = vk::ImageLayout::eUndefined;
    colorAttachment.finalLayout = vk::ImageLayout::ePresentSrcKHR;
     
    vk::AttachmentDescription depthAttachment;
    depthAttachment.format = FindDepthFormat();
    depthAttachment.samples = vk::SampleCountFlagBits::e1;
    depthAttachment.loadOp = vk::AttachmentLoadOp::eClear;
    depthAttachment.storeOp = vk::AttachmentStoreOp::eDontCare;
    depthAttachment.stencilLoadOp = vk::AttachmentLoadOp::eDontCare;
    depthAttachment.stencilStoreOp = vk::AttachmentStoreOp::eDontCare;
    depthAttachment.initialLayout = vk::ImageLayout::eUndefined;
    depthAttachment.finalLayout = vk::ImageLayout::eDepthStencilAttachmentOptimal;
     
    std::array<vk::AttachmentDescription, 2> attachments = { colorAttachment, depthAttachment };
     
    vk::AttachmentReference colorAttachmentRef;
    colorAttachmentRef.attachment = 0;
    colorAttachmentRef.layout = vk::ImageLayout::eColorAttachmentOptimal;
     
    vk::AttachmentReference depthAttachmentRef;
    depthAttachmentRef.attachment = 1;
    depthAttachmentRef.layout = vk::ImageLayout::eDepthStencilAttachmentOptimal;
     
    vk::SubpassDescription subpass;
    subpass.colorAttachmentCount = 1;
    subpass.pColorAttachments = &colorAttachmentRef;
    subpass.pDepthStencilAttachment = &depthAttachmentRef;
     
    vk::SubpassDependency dependency;
    dependency.srcSubpass = VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL;
    dependency.dstSubpass = 0;
    dependency.srcStageMask = vk::PipelineStageFlagBits::eColorAttachmentOutput;
    dependency.srcAccessMask = vk::AccessFlagBits();
    dependency.dstStageMask = vk::PipelineStageFlagBits::eColorAttachmentOutput;
    dependency.dstAccessMask = vk::AccessFlagBits::eColorAttachmentRead | vk::AccessFlagBits::eColorAttachmentWrite;
     
    vk::RenderPassCreateInfo renderPassInfo;
    renderPassInfo.attachmentCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(attachments.size());
    renderPassInfo.pAttachments = attachments.data();
    renderPassInfo.subpassCount = 1;
    renderPassInfo.pSubpasses = &subpass;
    renderPassInfo.dependencyCount = 1;
    renderPassInfo.pDependencies = &dependency;
     
    gameRenderPass = device.createRenderPass(renderPassInfo);
```

There is the code for ui rp:

```
vk::AttachmentDescription colorAttachment;
colorAttachment.format = swapChainImageFormat;
colorAttachment.samples = vk::SampleCountFlagBits::e1;
colorAttachment.loadOp = vk::AttachmentLoadOp::eLoad;
colorAttachment.storeOp = vk::AttachmentStoreOp::eStore;
colorAttachment.stencilLoadOp = vk::AttachmentLoadOp::eDontCare;
colorAttachment.stencilStoreOp = vk::AttachmentStoreOp::eDontCare;
colorAttachment.initialLayout = vk::ImageLayout::ePresentSrcKHR;
colorAttachment.finalLayout = vk::ImageLayout::ePresentSrcKHR;

vk::AttachmentDescription depthAttachment;
depthAttachment.format = FindDepthFormat();
depthAttachment.samples = vk::SampleCountFlagBits::e1;
depthAttachment.loadOp = vk::AttachmentLoadOp::eClear;
depthAttachment.storeOp = vk::AttachmentStoreOp::eDontCare;
depthAttachment.stencilLoadOp = vk::AttachmentLoadOp::eDontCare;
depthAttachment.stencilStoreOp = vk::AttachmentStoreOp::eDontCare;
depthAttachment.initialLayout = vk::ImageLayout::eUndefined;
depthAttachment.finalLayout = vk::ImageLayout::eDepthStencilAttachmentOptimal;

std::array<vk::AttachmentDescription, 2> attachments = { colorAttachment, depthAttachment };
  
vk::AttachmentReference colorAttachmentRef;
colorAttachmentRef.attachment = 0;
colorAttachmentRef.layout = vk::ImageLayout::eColorAttachmentOptimal;

vk::AttachmentReference depthAttachmentRef;
depthAttachmentRef.attachment = 1;
depthAttachmentRef.layout = vk::ImageLayout::eDepthStencilAttachmentOptimal;

vk::SubpassDescription subpass;
subpass.colorAttachmentCount = 1;
subpass.pColorAttachments = &colorAttachmentRef;
subpass.pDepthStencilAttachment = &depthAttachmentRef;

vk::SubpassDependency dependency;
dependency.srcSubpass = VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL;
dependency.dstSubpass = 0;
dependency.srcStageMask = vk::PipelineStageFlagBits::eColorAttachmentOutput;
dependency.srcAccessMask = vk::AccessFlagBits();
dependency.dstStageMask = vk::PipelineStageFlagBits::eColorAttachmentOutput;
dependency.dstAccessMask = vk::AccessFlagBits::eColorAttachmentRead | vk::AccessFlagBits::eColorAttachmentWrite;

vk::RenderPassCreateInfo renderPassInfo;
renderPassInfo.attachmentCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(attachments.size());
renderPassInfo.pAttachments = attachments.data();
renderPassInfo.subpassCount = 1;
renderPassInfo.pSubpasses = &subpass;
renderPassInfo.dependencyCount = 1;
renderPassInfo.pDependencies = &dependency;

uiRenderPass = device.createRenderPass(renderPassInfo);
```

And there is the code of my DrawFrame function:

```
device.waitForFences(1, &inFlightFences[currentFrame], true, UINT64_MAX);

uint32_t imageIndex;
device.acquireNextImageKHR(swapChain, UINT64_MAX, imageAvailableSemaphores[currentFrame], nullptr, &imageIndex);

if (imagesInFlight[imageIndex].operator!=(nullptr))
{
  device.waitForFences(1, &imagesInFlight[imageIndex], true, UINT64_MAX);
}
imagesInFlight[imageIndex] = inFlightFences[currentFrame];

vk::SubmitInfo submitInfo;

vk::Semaphore waitSemaphores[] = { imageAvailableSemaphores[currentFrame] };
vk::PipelineStageFlags waitStages[] = { vk::PipelineStageFlagBits::eColorAttachmentOutput };
submitInfo.waitSemaphoreCount = 1;
submitInfo.pWaitSemaphores = waitSemaphores;
submitInfo.pWaitDstStageMask = waitStages;

vk::Semaphore signalSemaphores[] = { renderFinishedSemaphores[currentFrame] };
submitInfo.signalSemaphoreCount = 1;
submitInfo.pSignalSemaphores = signalSemaphores;

device.resetFences(1, &inFlightFences[currentFrame]);

UpdateUniformBuffer(imageIndex);

UpdateUiCommandBuffer(imageIndex);

if (comandUpdateRequired[imageIndex])
{
  UpdateGameCommandBuffer(imageIndex);
  comandUpdateRequired[imageIndex] = false;
}

std::vector<vk::CommandBuffer> commands = { gameCommandBuffers[imageIndex], uiCommandBuffers[imageIndex] };
  
submitInfo.commandBufferCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(commands.size());
submitInfo.pCommandBuffers = commands.data();

graphicsQueue.submit(1, &submitInfo, inFlightFences[currentFrame]);

vk::PresentInfoKHR presentInfo;
presentInfo.waitSemaphoreCount = 1;
presentInfo.pWaitSemaphores = signalSemaphores;

vk::SwapchainKHR swapChains[] = { swapChain };
presentInfo.swapchainCount = 1;
presentInfo.pSwapchains = swapChains;
presentInfo.pImageIndices = &imageIndex;

presentQueue.presentKHR(presentInfo);

presentQueue.waitIdle();

currentFrame = (currentFrame + 1) % MAX_FRAMES_IN_FLIGHT;
```

And the result is:
[image: Bad result >:(]

As you can see, clear color is used to overwrite the results of my first render pass, what is not what I want.

Note that `load` and `store` operations already in use and it **still doesn't** work.

---

**UPDATE**

There is a code of my second cb:

```
device.freeCommandBuffers(commandPool, 1, &uiCommandBuffers[index]);

vk::CommandBufferAllocateInfo allocInfo;
allocInfo.commandPool = commandPool;
allocInfo.level = vk::CommandBufferLevel::ePrimary;
allocInfo.commandBufferCount = 1;

device.allocateCommandBuffers(&allocInfo, &uiCommandBuffers[index]);

vk::CommandBufferBeginInfo beginInfo;

uiCommandBuffers[index].begin(beginInfo);

std::array<vk::ClearValue, 2> clearValues;
clearValues[0].color = vk::ClearColorValue(std::array<float, 4>{ 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f });
clearValues[1].depthStencil = { 1.0f, 0 };

vk::RenderPassBeginInfo renderPassInfo;
renderPassInfo.renderPass = gameRenderPass;
renderPassInfo.framebuffer = uiSwapChainFramebuffers[index];
renderPassInfo.renderArea.offset = { 0, 0 };
renderPassInfo.renderArea.extent = swapChainExtent;
renderPassInfo.clearValueCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(clearValues.size()); // It doesn't work at all if I set clear values count to 0
renderPassInfo.pClearValues = clearValues.data();
//renderPassInfo.clearValueCount = 0;
//renderPassInfo.pClearValues = nullptr;

uiCommandBuffers[index].beginRenderPass(renderPassInfo, vk::SubpassContents::eInline);

auto drawData = ImGui::GetDrawData();
if (drawData)
{
    ImGui_ImplVulkan_RenderDrawData(drawData, uiCommandBuffers[index]);
}

uiCommandBuffers[index].endRenderPass();

uiCommandBuffers[index].end();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to render the UI using a second pass, just set the `storeOp` of the color attachment in the first render pass to `VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_STORE` and the `loadOp` for it in the second render pass to `VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_LOAD` to keep the contents.

Another option would be to do this in a single render pass, like I do in my samples. Just render your scene, and put the draw calls for the UI in the same render pass.

Comment: I already use load and store operations and it still doesn't work

Comment: Are you maybe doing an explicit clear in your second render pass? Can you add that code too?

Comment: Oh, god. I forgot to specify uiRenderPass instead of gameRenderPass in second (ui) command buffer. Yes, your answer is completely correct.